# React: Read Zip file using JSZip from the project directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jszip

I am trying to read a zip file which has images from the project directory in React.

When I open the Zip file from `<input type="file" />`, it works by taking the `event.target.files[0]` .
But when I put that same file in react project and then try to open it by giving a path , it doesnt work.

Example : "./test.zip"

My current code:

```
let jsZip = new JSZip();
jsZip.loadAsync("./test.zip").then(function (zip) {
         let imagess = [];
         Object.keys(zip.files).forEach(function (filename) {
            zip.files[filename].async("base64").then(function (fileData) {
               const image = document.createElement("img");
               image.src = "data:image/*;base64," + fileData;
               document.querySelector(".unziped-container").appendChild(image);
            });
         });
      });
```

I have been stuck on this for hours and the documentation is not helping either.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone coming across this can use **JSZip-utils** and write the following code

```
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("../path/file.zip", function (err, data) {
         if (err) {
            throw err;
         }
         const jsZip = new JSZip();
         jsZip.loadAsync(data).then(function (zip) {
            Object.keys(zip.files).forEach(function (filename) {
               zip.files[filename].async("base64").then(function (fileData) {
                  const image = document.createElement("img");
                  image.src = "data:image/*;base64," + fileData;
                  const unziped = document.querySelector(".unziped-container");
                  unziped.appendChild(image);
               });
            });
         });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

[the documentation](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load_async.html) seems pretty clear: the first argument to `loadAsync` is the zip file data, but you're passing it a string.

(and what you're tring to do won't work anyway.  your React code is running in the browser and has no knowledge of filesystem paths or filenames.)

Comment: It worked, All I had to do was use Jszip utils , instead of JSZip .thanks for your answer